# Django-allauth google authentication not working in production (apache2 + mod_wsgi)

Tags: django, apache, django-allauth

I have deployed my django web application on my institute server using apache and mod_wsgi and I am using django-allauth google authentication. My institute network uses few proxy servers to interact with the Internet.

Google authentication works fine while I am running app on localhost, but as soon as I migrate the app to https_://fusion.*******.ac.in, google authentication shows following

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1oOQ.png)

callback uri: https_://fusion.*******.ac.in/accounts/google/login/callback/

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Did you add your production call back url , ie, ```https://fusion.xxxx.ac.in/login/redirect/```  in  Google API credentials?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge, is it different from `https://fusion.xxxx.ac.in/accounts/google/login/callback/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following lines in your wsgi file.

```
import os

http_proxy  = "host:port"
https_proxy = "host:port"
ftp_proxy   = "host:port"

proxyDict = { 
 "http"  : http_proxy, 
 "https" : https_proxy, 
 "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
}

os.environ["PROXIES"] = proxyDict
```